# Where can I download QRU-1 dataset?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research, search-engine

In the paper [QRU-1: A Public Dataset for Promoting Query Representation and Understanding Research](http://www.hangli-hl.com/uploads/3/4/4/6/34465961/wscd_qru-1.pdf), writers introduce that dataset. I want to download it but when I search for it there is no result. Even the download link in the paper is not working. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset is not available for download on the SIGIR workshop website, but is still available on the Microsoft Research website: check [this link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/d6e8c8f2-721f-4222-81fa-4251b6c33752/default.aspx).